# Saving a decimal query result as a variable- Must declare the scalar variable (INNER JOINS, 2 DECIMAL PLACES, PRECISION AND SCALE SET)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Calculating the avg:**

```
SELECT 

round(AVG(P.LiczbaUczniow/E.WypełnioneEtaty),2)

FROM [dbo].[UczniowieWojs] P

INNER JOIN EtatyWypełnioneWoj  E ON E.WOJ=P.idTerytWojewodztwo
```

*RESULT: 9.38*

**DECLARING THE VARIABLE:**

```
DECLARE @ŚrednioUczniówNaNauczycielaPL decimal(3,2);
```

**TRYING TO SAVE THE VARIABLE:**

```
SELECT 

@ŚrednioUczniówNaNauczycielaPL=round(AVG(P.LiczbaUczniow/E.WypełnioneEtaty),2)

FROM [dbo].[UczniowieWojs] P

INNER JOIN EtatyWypełnioneWoj  E ON E.WOJ=P.idTerytWojewodztwo
```

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 305 Must declare the scalar variable
> "@ŚrednioUczniówNaNauczycielaPL".

**What I've tried to resolve it:**

1. I've read the documentation of decimal datatype.
2. Google
3. Similar topics on stackoverflow - they all seem to refer to scale and precision which I think I got right. Yet, it's still wrong.

I've been working on it and sincerely cannot find the solution. I'd appreciate pointing me towards the answer.

Thanks

Comment: Are the declaration and the `SELECT` in the same badge? And it's probably not the best idea to use characters not in 7-bit ASCII for identifiers.

Comment: I've googled 'badge+SQL' yet haven't found the answer. What does it mean whether they're in the same badge?

They are written right below each other. Firstly the variable and right below it, the calculation.

As for the characters - noted, thank you.

Comment: That should be "batch", @Fortis . A variable only persists for the batch it was declared in, and can only be reference within the same scope. Your question gives the impression you have 2 batches, and thus the latter reference to `@ŚrednioUczniówNaNauczycielaPL` fails, as the variable no longer exists.

Comment: Oops... Yeah, that was an error of mine, i meant "batch" not "badge"... How stupid of me...

Comment: In other words, do you have a `GO` batch separator between the `declare` statement and your `select` statement?

Comment: @Larnu You seem to be right! I'm not sure whether this is what you meant, but does moving the semicolon to the very bottom like this:

`DECLARE @ŚrednioUczniówNaNauczycielaPL decimal(3,2) 

SELECT 

@ŚrednioUczniówNaNauczycielaPL=round(AVG(P.LiczbaUczniow/E.WypełnioneEtaty),2)

FROM [dbo].[UczniowieWojs] P

INNER JOIN EtatyWypełnioneWoj  E ON E.WOJ=P.idTerytWojewodztwo;`

make it one badge? Because when I run this code it produces a success. 

Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I did not have a GO separator. There was a semicolon though that seems to be the culprit.

Comment: A semicolon is a statement terminator, not a batch separator, @Fortis (`GO` is a batch separator in applications such as SSMS, `sqlcmd` and ADS). You should be terminating *all* your statements, as no not doing so is deprecated. The semicolon in the `DECLARE` won't be causing the issue.

Comment: @Larnu Okay, you're right. It was not about semicolon. I've just checked it out and it's about me running these statements separately.
If I firstly run DECLARE ... and then run SELECT, then I get the error.

But when I run it together, then I get a success.

Comment: That would be in separate batches as well then, @Fortis ...

Comment: @Larnu can you post your answers as a solution? I could then mark it as solved.

Comment: This was, if I am honest, more of a non-reproducible error, @Fortis . As the problem was that you were simply running the statement that references the variable without declaring the variable.

Comment: Okay, thank you for kind help guys

Answer (score 0):

@Larnu, @stickybit, @AlwaysLearning pointed out that a variable must be in the same badge. And I was running the Declare and Select commands separately, which made them separate things. That was the reason for the error.

If I had used a GO command in between of these statements that would also have produced the erroneous result.

Semicolon turned out to be fine because it isn't a batch separator.

**To sum it up - no 'go' between the statements and run them altogether.**